# Can I tell from the system log, whether XFS was cleanly unmounted on the previous shutdown?

Tags: linux, logs, xfs

Is there an XFS equivalent of the fsck.ext4 message "recovering journal"?  (See 
[Does "recovering journal" prove an unclean shutdown/unmount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441511/does-recovering-journal-prove-an-unclean-shutdown-unmount) ).

[`fsck.xfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xfsprogs/fsck.xfs.8.en.html) is a no-op.  So does the kernel log a message, when you mount an XFS filesystem that was not unmounted cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a direct equivalent.

```
[27927.296390] XFS (sdb4): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[27927.869545] XFS (sdb4): Ending clean mount
[27942.761564] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 31
[27943.011211] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[27960.810143] XFS (sdb4): Unmounting Filesystem
[27960.811247] XFS (sdb4): metadata I/O error in "xlog_iodone" at daddr 0x58b10a len 64 error 5
[27960.812077] XFS (sdb4): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x2) called from line 1271 of file fs/xfs/xfs_log.c.  Return address = 00000000758bdd7c
[27960.812708] XFS (sdb4): Log I/O Error Detected.  Shutting down filesystem
[27960.812728] XFS (sdb4): Unable to update superblock counters. Freespace may not be correct on next mount.
[27960.813349] XFS (sdb4): Please umount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)

...

[28509.842965]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[28509.846156] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[28517.755990] XFS (sdb4): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[28518.328431] XFS (sdb4): Ending clean mount
```

`file -s /dev/sdb4` is able to show when an ext4 filesystem "needs journal recovery", but it does not detect any difference when I test an uncleanly unmounted XFS filesystem.

`xfs_repair` does not show any difference either.  In fact, the list of common messages in  [`man xfs_repair`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xfsprogs/xfs_repair.8.en.html) do not include anything about journal replay.  Instead:

> The xfs_repair utility cannot repair an XFS file system with a dirty log. To clear the log, mount and unmount the XFS file system. If the log is corrupt and cannot be replayed, use the -L option ("force log zeroing") to clear the log, that is, xfs_repair -L /dev/device. Be aware that this may result in further corruption or data loss.
>
> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/xfsrepair

While ext4 maintains special flags to indicate an unclean unmount, it sounds like XFS only maintains the journal.  If the journal is empty then it is "clean"; there is nothing to repair/recover/replay.

(If your OS wishes to detect unclean shutdowns, then it must do so itself, like Windows does :-).